# Masonry messing up Bootstrap nav-bar in mobile view

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, masonry

I am trying to set up a menu-bar using bootstrap that switches to a stacked drop down hamburger bar on mobile. 
Everything works flawlessly without masonry included. But unfortunately, this project needs masonry to display images. 
[image: Nav-bar expanded in mobile without Masonry]

And this is what my result looks like with masonry.
[image: Nav-bar expanded in mobile with Masonry cs+js included]

The code for the nav-bar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#divMenuOptions" aria-expanded="false"
                    style="margin-top:20px;margin-botton:0px">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          </div>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="divMenuOptions" style="margin-top:10px">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="/faq">FAQ</a></li>
              <li><a href="/contactus">Contact Us</a></li>
              <li><a href="/recently-viewed">Recently Viewed</a></li>
              <li><a href="/favorites">Favorites</a></li>
            </ul>
            <form id="image_url_form" method="POST" action="/classify_url" class= "navbar-form navbar-left visible-md-block visible-lg-block hidden-xs hidden-sm">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name = "url" class="form-control" style="width:340px;" id="image_url_input" placeholder="Place image url here and hit enter!">
              </div>
            </form>
            <form action="/fileupload" method="POST" id = "theform" enctype="multipart/form-data" class= "navbar-form" style="float:left;">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="button" id="btnBrowseFile" class="btn btn-primary" value="Browse for files"/>
                <input type="file" id="thefile" name="file" style="display:none"></input>
                <!-- class="btn btn-default" -->
              </div>
            </form>
            <p id="file-name" class="margin-10 bold-10"></p> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

I don't know exactly what part of the Masonry framework is causing this to happen. Is there a way I could find that out? And is there a possible work-around?

EDIT:
I have found part of the issue, but still don't know how to fix it.
[image]

Comment: You'll need to post the masonry related code.

Comment: Literally all I do is include the masonry css and js files. Don't even use it anywhere. Here's the full code: http://codeshare.io/7eRRR

Comment: Which Masonry library are you using?

Comment: I am using the desandro Masonry.

Comment: That's what I assumed but I don't believe that there is a default stylesheet for Masonry. Can you post that stylesheet?

Comment: Here it is: http://codeshare.io/6mxOk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by commenting out all the .nav stylings in masonry.css. Idk if this is bad practice, but it fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

You may try gridster instead of masonry if that's an option